# Align <select> combobox vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have this `CSS` style for my `<select>` comboboxes:

```
select
{
margin: 10px 0 0 40px;
min-width: 100px;
}
```

**I want align two comboboxes vertically.** I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
<form>
   <select>
     ...
   </select>
   <br /> <!-- This has no effect -->
   <select>
     ...
   </select>
</form>
```

Instead, they are positioned horizontally. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your CSS to:

```
select
{
margin: 10px 0 0 40px;
min-width: 100px;
display:block;
}
```

On a side note, given the code you posted above only, it should [work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CHpYg/) without having to use `display:block`. You must have other CSS that causes them to be inline.

Comment: This did the trick. I'm wondering what other CSS could conflict with my `select`. Can this display style be inherited somehow?